# Capitalizing the chapter name in the table of contents, scrbook

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

So I am trying to capitalize the chapter name in the toc to distinguish it from the section name. I do not really have an idea what I am doing. So here is what i tried:

1. The docs clearly say to not use `\MakeUppercase` which does not work.
2. I cannot get `\uppercase` to work, it spaces out the text, ignores any other formatting (the \hfill), and resets the font set for the page number.
3. Using expl3 to use the `to_uppercase` command as an expandable command just results in it printing out .55emi but also with a reset font.
4. I wish i could use the `onstartentry` and `onendentry` from the koma-script doc, but they are not working for me either. Otherwise I could probably make an uppercase environment.
5. My current workaround is setting any chapter added to the toc as already in uppercase by renewing `\addchaptertocentry`, which has the annoying side effect, that so are the hyperlinks from hyperref.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{AlegreyaSans, blindtext, color}
\newcommand{\mediumsansfont}{\AlegreyaSansMedium}
\newcommand{\regularsansfont}{\sffamily}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    pagenumberformat={\color{blue}\mediumsansfont},
    indent=0em,
    linefill=\hfill,
    entryformat={\regularsansfont\bfseries\color{blue}}
]{default}{chapter}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    pagenumberformat={\color{black}\mediumsansfont},
    indent=0em,
    linefill=\hfill,
    entryformat={\regularsansfont\bfseries\color{blue}}
]{default}{section}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    pagenumberformat={\mediumsansfont},
    indent=1.5em,
    linefill=\hfill,
    entryformat={\mediumsansfont}
]{default}{subsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this have some side effects.

> Didn't pay attention to your question. Is this the method
> you mentioned in the 5th point? If so, I probably need to delete this.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{AlegreyaSans, blindtext, color}
\newcommand{\mediumsansfont}{\AlegreyaSansMedium}
\newcommand{\regularsansfont}{\sffamily}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    pagenumberformat={\color{blue}\mediumsansfont},
    indent=0em,
    linefill=\hfill,
    entryformat={\regularsansfont\bfseries\color{blue}}
]{default}{chapter}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    pagenumberformat={\color{black}\mediumsansfont},
    indent=0em,
    linefill=\hfill,
    entryformat={\regularsansfont\bfseries\color{blue}}
]{default}{section}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    pagenumberformat={\mediumsansfont},
    indent=1.5em,
    linefill=\hfill,
    entryformat={\mediumsansfont}
]{default}{subsection}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\addchaptertocentry}{{#1}{#2}}{{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\uppercase{#2}}{#2}}}{}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does it without side effects. Thank you. I just copied the definition from the komascript which calls `addtocentrydefault` and in the call, i just used MakeUppercase which leads to sideeffects.